# Parsing JSON file from folder - NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have got a file downloaded from AWS S3 to my NSTemporaryDirectory using this code:

```
let downloadFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("FILENAME")
    let downloadingFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:downloadFilePath)
    let downloadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest();
    downloadRequest.bucket = "Bucketname";
    downloadRequest.key = "FileName";
    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;
```

The file = .json file
the apps content is all saved on the JSON file, therefore i need to redirect the file from the NSTemporaryDirectory in order for the content to appear on the application.

Does anyone know the parse function in order to load the data from my JSON file into the application?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to move a file to the main bundle to display it. I don't know what kind of file it is, but you should be able to provide the path of the file to whatever system you want to use to use the file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the main bundle, so this isn't going to work.

There are a few directories under your control, for example the home directory, the application support directory, cache directories, or possibly the document directory.

Comment: Okay, i'm really sorry but i dont understand what you are saying? what methods can i use in order to display the content?

Comment: @Kumar What do you mean here by "display" that you think would happen if you moved the file?

Comment: when i click run for the simulator, i want the file to be shown on the simulator?

Comment: What do you mean par "shown" ? Within your app ? Displayed in a textfield ? A shortcut on the home page (don't want that please)

Comment: no so because the file is a .json file that has articles, so when the simulator runs, it will show the articles within the app

Comment: Ok so you want to parse it and display the data parsed from within your app ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm rather new to this, do you have an example that i could see please?

Comment: The json won't magically display on your application. Do you want to display the raw json file? You could read it into a string (NSString(contentsOfFile...) and then display it on a multi line label? Or you could parse the json (EVReflection might help), and display the data appropriately.

Comment: @raf yeah i think i need to parse the json through in order to display it appropriately, because my json is spilt into different view controllers as they all showcase different parts of content

Answer (score 0):

As gnasher729 notes, you can't modify the main bundle itself, but there's no reason to here. You don't need to move the file in order to display it. You can read from your temporary directory. It's inside your application sandbox, and there's nothing special about it (it doesn't even get cleaned up for you either, so that's your responsibility if you need that).

The temp directory isn't backed up, so if you want that, you should move this to your documents directory. See `NSFileManager moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` if you want to do that (or just download to your documents directory in the first place).

Comment: okay, thank you i will look into that. 
i am little confused, but i will figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

So after downloading the File:

```
let downloadFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("FILENAME")
let downloadingFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:downloadFilePath)
let downloadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest();
downloadRequest.bucket = "Bucketname";
downloadRequest.key = "FileName";
downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;
```

i have to submit the download request - as seen below:

```
     // submit download request
    let transferManager: AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager();
    print("Downloading started, please wait...");

    transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.defaultExecutor(), block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        print("TASK:::::: \(task)");
            if (task.error != nil){
                print("Error Downloading");
            }else{
                self.readFile()
                print("Download complete");
            }

        return nil;
        }, cancellationToken: nil)


}
```

create a function that will parse your JSON file through the temp directory, using AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON:

```
func readFile() {
    // JSON parsing step (from temporary directory)
    let path = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("FILENAME")
    do {
        let readFile:NSString? = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let json = JSON.parse(readFile as String!)
        for (_, subJson) in json["FILECONTENT"] {
            let version = subJson["FILECONTENT"].string
            let newsletter = Edition(Version: version!)
            self.editions.append(ARRAYNAME!)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        //print(readFile)
    } catch {
    }

}
```

this will showcase the text on your application when ran. 
I am trying to get the images to do the something now.